# AngularJS custom directive $location.path not working

Tags: angularjs

```
    merchantApp.directive('logout', function(common,$location){
return {
    restrict: 'A',        
     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                               
         element.click(function(){     
             common.clearCookies();            
             $location.path("/merchantlogin");        
         })                            
    }
};
```

})

This is my custom directive. I want redirect to merchant login page. The clearCookies function also working fine, But redirect is not working please help.....

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'... Did you debug it on console? Do you have DI problems?

Comment: What is the  error then?

Answer (score 3):

Add $scope.$apply() after changing